# How to use oracle outer join with a filter where clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g, outer-join

If i write a sql:

```
select * 
from a,b 
where     a.id=b.id(+) 
      and b.val="test"
```

and i want all records from a where  corresponding record in b does not exist or it exists with val="test", is this the correct query?

Comment: How many table do you have and what is a.b and c ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You're much better off using the ANSI syntax

```
SELECT *
  FROM a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON( a.id = b.id and
                             b.val = 'test' )
```

You can do the same thing using Oracle's syntax as well but it gets a bit hinkey

```
SELECT *
  FROM a, 
       b
 WHERE a.id = b.id(+)
   AND b.val(+) = 'test'
```

Note that in both cases, I'm ignoring the `c` table since you don't specify a join condition.  And I'm assuming that you don't really want to join A to B and then generate a Cartesian product with C.

Comment: Is this correct:
SELECT *  FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id(+) AND b.val(+) = 'test' and b.col2(+) = 'test2';
I wish to get all rows from a if corresponding row in b is null or corresponding row in b has  col2='test2' and val = 'test'

So, it is either null OR (col2='test2' AND val = 'test')

Answer (score 1):

Move the condition into the `JOIN` clause and use the ANSI standard join pattern.

```
SELECT NameYourFields,...
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.ID
AND B.VAL = 'test'
INNER JOIN C
ON ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A LEFT OUTER JOIN is one of the JOIN operations that allow you to specify a join clause. It preserves the unmatched rows from the first (left) table, joining them with a NULL row in the shape of the second (right) table.

So you can do as follows :

SELECT 
   FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b 
   ON a.id = b.id

--Note that you have used double quote "test" which is not used for varchar in SQL you should use single quote 'test'

AND b.val = 'test';

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM abc a, xyz b
 WHERE a.id = b.id
   AND b.val = 'test'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Thanks for your contribution but it would be extremely helpful if you could expand your answer with a few details about how it answers Victors question.