# Join two tables when there is no value in one table

Tags: oracle, join

I have two tables, ROLE and ROLE_DESC.

ROLE looks like this.

```
PS_ROLE_SEQ  NUMBER,    
PS_SEQ       NUMBER,    
ROLE_TYPE            VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),    
SOURCE               VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)
```

ROLE_DESC looks like this.

```
ROLE_TYPE  VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),    
ROLE_NAME  VARCHAR2(16 CHAR)
```

As you expect, ROLE_TYPE of ROLE and ROLE_TYPE of ROLE_DESC reference each other.
There are three entities in ROLE_DESC, like this.

```
ROLE_TYPE   ROLE_NAME
A           Account
M           Manager
S           Sales
```

I would like to make this string for a particular PS_SEQ using where clause.

```
(Account + ":" + ROLE.SOURCE + "|" + Manager + ":" + ROLE.SOURCE + "|" + Sales + ":" + ROLE.SOURCE)
```

Sometimes, ROLE table does not have whole ROLE_TYPE, for example, it only has Account and Manager. 
In that case, ROLE.SOURCE of Sales become just "".
And, ROLE_DESC is dynamic, the number of entities can be changed.

Is there any way I can query this easily?

Comment: I don't understand the issue, what do you expect to get instead of "" ?

Comment: If there is no value for Sales, it should print like Account:PPP|Manager:TTT|Sales:|

Comment: If there is no value for Manager, it should print like this Account:PPP|Manager:|Sales:RRR.

Comment: And now what does it print ?

Comment: Actually, I can't make the query for printing that, so I am asking you.

Comment: @YoYo Are you sure? Come someone and immediately POSSIBLE DUPLICATE or DOWN VOTE.

Comment: Not exactly duplicate, but refer to answers of [How to use oracle outer join with a filter where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390588/how-to-use-oracle-outer-join-with-a-filter-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select ROLE_DESC.ROLE_TYPE, ROLE_DESC.ROLE_NAME, ROLE.SOURCE 
FROM ROLE_DESC
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE
ON (ROLE_DESC.role_type=ROLE.role_type and ROLE.PS_SEQ = 111)
```

Comment: The role_desc table is dynamic, so I can't make it static.

Comment: Please edit this question with the sample data you posted in the other one, then please close it, because it's a duplicate. After reading your second question, I edited y answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LISTAGG (role_name || ':' || source, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY role_name)
  FROM (SELECT ROLE_DESC.ROLE_TYPE, ROLE_DESC.ROLE_NAME, ROLE.SOURCE
          FROM ROLE_DESC 
           LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE 
           ON ROLE_DESC.role_type = ROLE.role_type AND ROLE.PS_SEQ = 111)
```