# outer join two tables

Tags: oracle, join, outer-join

I have two tables, ROLE and ROLE_DESC.

ROLE looks like this.

```
PS_ROLE_SEQ  NUMBER,    
PS_SEQ       NUMBER,    
ROLE_TYPE            VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),    
SOURCE               VARCHAR2(128 CHAR)
```

ROLE_DESC looks like this.

```
ROLE_TYPE  VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),    
ROLE_NAME  VARCHAR2(16 CHAR)
```

As you expect, `ROLE_TYPE` of ROLE `and` `ROLE_TYPE` of `ROLE_DESC` reference each other. There are three entities in `ROLE_DESC`, like this.

```
ROLE_TYPE   ROLE_NAME
A           Account
M           Manager
S           Sales
```

I would like to print whole `role_type` and `role_name` by joining two tables even thought `ROLE` table does not have a certain `ROLE_TYPE`. 
For example, if there is no 'S' `role_type` for PS_SEQ = 111. I tried, this, but I only got below.

```
select ROLE_DESC.ROLE_TYPE, ROLE_DESC.ROLE_NAME, ROLE.SOURCE 
FROM ROLE_DESC
LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE
ON ROLE_DESC.role_type=ROLE.role_type
where ROLE.PS_SEQ = 111
```

Result:

```
A   Account Bob
M   Manager Sandy
```

Actually, I would like to get following.

```
A   Account Bob
M   Manager Sandy
S   Sales
```

Does outer join does make it possible? Could you please give some clue for this question?

Comment: Isn't it the same question than [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37027903/join-two-tables-when-there-is-no-value-in-one-table)?

Comment: It is different, but the purpose is same. if you want, I can delete the previous question. I am sorry for being confusion.

Comment: I suggest to edit the first question, then close this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use oracle outer join with a filter where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390588/how-to-use-oracle-outer-join-with-a-filter-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
select ROLE_DESC.ROLE_TYPE, ROLE_DESC.ROLE_NAME, ROLE.SOURCE
  FROM ROLE_DESC
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLE
ON ROLE_DESC.role_type=ROLE.role_type AND ROLE.PS_SEQ = 111
```

When it is in WHERE clause, you filters the result. And in the result ROLE.PS_SEQ is Null for Sales and Null <> 111